# session.gc_maxlifetime not expiring PHP Session

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I have put:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1
```

in my `.htaccess` file so my PHP Sessions should expire after 1 second but they are not.

I set a session and its still set after a few hours.

If i look at `phpinfo()` the `session.gc_maxlifetime` is set to 1 on the local value

any ideas why this is not working

Comment: the maxlifetime only applies when the garbage collector actually kicks in. You need to modify the gc_probability and gc_divisor settings as well, so the GC will kick in more frequently. default config is 1/100, meaning that's a 1% chance of a GC run being performed.

Comment: what do i need to change those to?

Comment: whatever probability you want the GC to run at. For development, go with 1/1, but do NOT forget to change it back to something more reasonable, otherwise you're going to be going all Godzilla on your sessions.

Answer (score 0):

As the php manual says:

[session.gc_maxlifetime integer](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) :

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up.
>   Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on
>   [session.gc_probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) and [session.gc_divisor](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor)).
>
> Note: If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the
>   session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning
>   the data. In this case, use this directive together with
>   session.save_path.

session.gc_probability integer:

> session.gc_probability in conjunction with session.gc_divisor is used to manage probability that the gc (garbage collection) routine is
>   started. Defaults to 1. See session.gc_divisor for details. 
>   session.gc_divisor integer

session.gc_divisor:

> coupled with session.gc_probability defines the probability that the
>   gc (garbage collection) process is started on every session
>   initialization. The probability is calculated by using
>   gc_probability/gc_divisor, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that
>   the GC process starts on each request. session.gc_divisor defaults to
>   100.

You also can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/6521116).